# How to correctly read .exr files in python?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, openexr

like the title says I want to read .exr image files which encode depth.

Sample image - displayed using openexr-viewer[image] (Source: [Synscapes datatset](https://synscapes.on.liu.se/))

I tried:

```
os.environ["OPENCV_IO_ENABLE_OPENEXR"]="1"

import cv2
import numpy as np

exr_file_path = 'path/to/file'

image = cv2.imread(exr_file_path,  cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR | cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)
```

The dimensions of image are correct, but the image is completely filled with zeros.

Debugger shows this:

```
->image.shape
      (720, 1440)
->np.unique(image)
      array([0.], dtype=float32)
```

What am I missing ?

My goal would be to create a function which accepts a path to an .exr file and returns the image as a pillow image.

Currently this is what I have:

```
def exr_to_pil(exr_file_path): 
    exr_file_path = str(exr_file_path)
    image = cv2.imread(exr_file_path,  cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR | cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)
    
    # Debugger stops here to check output of imread
    img = Image.fromarray(image.astype('uint8'))
    
    return img
```

Comment: Doesn't look like it's very straightforward with cv2 alone: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/22592#issuecomment-1266590674

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem using the OpenEXR an Imath libs

At first had some problems installing OpenEXR but could fix is thanks to this answer in [this](https://github.com/jamesbowman/openexrpython/issues/28) post.

> On MacOS with the same python version I hit similar errors and everything worked when installing with this command: pip install git+https://github.com/jamesbowman/openexrpython.git

Code for depth map loading is:

```
import OpenEXR as exr
import Imath

def exr_to_array(filepath: Path):
    exrfile = exr.InputFile(filepath.as_posix())
    raw_bytes = exrfile.channel('Z', Imath.PixelType(Imath.PixelType.FLOAT))
    depth_vector = numpy.frombuffer(raw_bytes, dtype=numpy.float32)
    height = exrfile.header()['displayWindow'].max.y + 1 - exrfile.header()['displayWindow'].min.y
    width = exrfile.header()['displayWindow'].max.x + 1 - exrfile.header()['displayWindow'].min.x
    depth_map = numpy.reshape(depth_vector, (height, width))
    return depth_map
```

Comment: Ah, was just about to post pretty much the same answer. Glad you got it solved too!